# ReactJS component cannot resolve a domain name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use a component like

```
const React = require('react');
const dns = require('dns');

class DnsResolver extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        dns.resolve('https://www.google.com', (err, addresses) => {
            this.setState({
                address: addresses
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.address}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = DnsResolver;
```

the result is `0.0.0.0`. Somehow, the browser cannot resolve the address. Why might this happen?

Comment: You cannot use DNS from a browser.

Comment: Says where? Then what is the `dns.resolve()` function for? [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve)

Comment: That's the web extensions API, not in-page JavaScript

Comment: The initial point of my problem started when I tried to use `mongodb` npm module. It uses `dns` npm module to resolve the mongodb address, but since it runs at the frontend, `dns.resolve()` translates into this web extension function. NodeJS `dns` returns an array but web extension `dns` may return `string`. That's where the trouble starts. I maybe should not use `mongodb` at the frontend.

Comment: You cannot use MongoDB from the browser either.  You need a backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dns` is a native NodeJS module, it is intended to use in the server.